# Is there a word that means "walk away disregarding"?

Tags: word-request

> John turns and walks away, disregarding Mike's response.

Is there a word (verb) that means "walk away disregarding"? Is there any word that means "walk in upset or sad"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a word that means John walks away necessarily, but I can think of a couple words that capture that sentiment:

> **[spurn](http://www.wordnik.com/words/spurn)** (*verb*) To reject disdainfully or contemptuously; to scorn; to reject with disdain; to refuse to consort with; to treat with contempt
>
> **[snub](http://www.wordnik.com/words/snub)** (*verb*) To ignore or behave coldly toward; to dismiss or turn down; to rebuke with a severe or sarcastic reply or remark; to slight designedly; to treat with deliberate neglect
>
> **[scorn](http://www.wordnik.com/words/scorn)** (*verb*)  To reject or refuse with derision (*noun*) The expression of such an attitude in behavior or speech; derision.

Once again, it's possible to scorn or snub someone and **not** walk away, but I think these words are a bit more forceful than *disregard*. So, you could say:

> John snubs Mike, and walks away.
> John disregards Mike, and walks away with scorn.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to take two completely different concepts and put them into one word, so that's not likely to happen. The fact that he's walking away is completely separate from the fact that he is disregarding Mike's response. Consider these sentences, which have similar structure:

> John turns and walks away, eating an ice cream cone.
>
> John turns and walks away, checking his phone for messages.

There isn't going to be a word that means "walks away, eating" or "walks away, checking" either. These are two completely separate actions; if we had a word for every possible combination of actions we'd never be able to keep track of them! If you consider this in your native language I'd guess this is likely true there as well.